Bootstrapping a gaussian and best fit data
I have the following code which provides the best fit curve for my given data. I am not sure how to bootstrap it and use that to find the 95% confidence interval.
This is my code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as plb
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

data = np.loadtxt('gaussian.dat')
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]

n = len(x)                          
mean = sum(x*y)/n                   
sigma = sum(y*(x-mean)**2)/n        

def gauss(x,a,x0,sigma):
    return a*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

popt,pcov = curve_fit(gauss,x,y,p0=[1,mean,sigma])

plt.plot(x,y,'b+:',label='data')
plt.plot(x,gauss(x,*popt),'ro:',label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Gaussian Fit vs Actual Data')
plt.xlabel('x-values')
plt.ylabel('y-values')
plt.show()


Let's say that x, y are generated from the gauss with an error:
# -- generating custom random dataset 
# skip this part if you are using data from the file
x = np.arange(-100,100,step=0.1)

a = 2.4
x0 = 0.1
sigma = 3

def gauss(x,a,x0,sigma):
    return a*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

# y is a gauss process with random error introduced from the measurement
y = gauss(x, a, x0, sigma) + 0.1 * np.random.normal(size = x.shape[0])

# <--- end of generating dataset


# fitting the curve
n = len(x)                          
mean = sum(x*y)/n                   
sigma = sum(y*(x-mean)**2)/n

popt,pcov = curve_fit(gauss,x,y,p0=[1,mean,sigma])


Then to generate confidence interval in any point (for example in x=0.2) you can sample parameters, apply gauss function with this parameters and get y in this point. Then get 2.5% and 97.5% quantile to plot 95% confidence interval:
def bootstrap_gauss(x: float, popt: np.ndarray, pcov: np.ndarray):
    arr_bootstrap_y = []

    # bootstrapping parameters 100 times
    for t in range(100):
        a, mean, sigma = np.random.multivariate_normal(popt, pcov)
        y = gauss(x,a,x0,sigma)
        arr_bootstrap_y.append(y)

    return arr_bootstrap_y


conf_interval = bootstrap_gauss(0.2, popt, pcov)
# 95% confidence interval
q1, q2 = np.quantile(conf_interval, [0.025,0.975])
print("Confidence interval:", q1, q2)

The remaining question is how to vectorize this calculations to make it more efficient...
def get_conf_gaus(x: float,
                  popt: np.ndarray, 
                  pcov: np.ndarray,
                  n_boostrap:int = 100):
    
    params = np.random.multivariate_normal(popt, pcov, size = [n_boostrap])
    a = params[:,0]
    mu = params[:,1]
    sigma = params[:,2]
    
    bootstrap_y = gauss(0.2,a,mu,sigma)
    conf = np.quantile(bootstrap_y, [0.025,0.975])
    return conf

conf = get_conf_gaus(0.2, popt, pcov)
# outputs [2.37079969, 2.41727759]



how does it relate to my code

Hi, I understand that I'm not using your data directly, but exact  'x','y' inputs doesn't change the way you bootstrap the confidence interval. To bootstrap confidence interval you need to run my functions on each 'x' where you'd like to get interval values. Hope this make sense.

i mean, how did you generate the initial parameters, a=2.4 , x0=0,1, sigma = 3

Sry, this part maybe is not very clear. It is related to generating custom dataset. You can skip it, because you already have x and y from the file.

if i understand correctly, it returns slightly different values each time because that is how bootstrapping works (creating rough estimates)

Bootstrapping usually referes to process of resampling data using given or estimated probabilities. This is needed, because sometimes you are working with very complex functions for which it might be hard to estimate true probability distributions. Thus you will resample parameters with known distributions and then use them as an input to a complex function to get function value. And basically bootstrapping allow you to estimate quantiles or other statistics of a complex function with unknown distribution.

In simpler words - bootstrapping referes to a process of sampling everything that have known distributions and testing how it affects your outputs.
